# Xcode 7 error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios9, xcode7

I'm getting an error when i open my app in xcode 7:

[image]

I've tried everything from re adding all of my linked libraries to editing the build settings, but this error will not go away? I've tried google searching this, but all the answers i came accross wont work. What do i do?

The error does not show up in xcode 6, why is it in only xcode 7?

Comment: There isn't really enough information here for me to debug this, but try a couple things: change deployment target to a lower version and see if it is a version problem, or you can move Bolts framework to trash, redownload, and add it to the project, or (and i'm not sure this would do anything) but in your Build Settings set Enable Bitcode to NO.

Comment: It Worked! I set the deployment target to ios 6.0 and the error went away. Post this as an answer so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change deployment target to a lower version and see if it is a version problem. Try deployment target to iOS 6.0 :)

However, this could be dangerous if you are using APIs that only support iOS 8 and above.  Use this fix cautiously to make sure not to cause any problems in other areas of your project.  Therefore, be sure to test on an iOS 6.0 device or iOS 6.0 simulator.

Comment: This is dangerous because the OP seems to want to support only iOS 8 and later. Changing the Deployment Target to iOS 6 means the app will run on iOS 6 devices and later. But the code could be full of API use added since iOS 8 and all of these APIs will cause crashes on devices with iOS 6 and 7. The issue should be fixed properly. Not through an unneeded hack like this.

Comment: That is a good point.  I updated my answer to give light to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Bolts pod dependency is somehow added to the Build Phases pane under **Link Binary With Libraries** of your Targets settings. Try by removing the library ".a" file from the Build Phase.